# How to call action method from javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an application which uses MVC and KnockoutJS. In my application is a grid in a view which shows a knockout observable array bound as data to a html grid.

I want to navigate to another view when a user clicks on any of the row from the grid. When a user clicks on any row I capture the id from that row, and call a javascript method which uses Ajax to invoke an action method from a controller.

I am able to call the action method from javascript method using `$.ajax`, but I am not able to redirect to the other view.

How can this be done?

Comment: Ajax calls stay on the same page. If you want to redirect after an ajax call use `window.location.href=...`

Comment: Just use the `<a href="">...` thats what it was designed for....

Comment: i think question is self explainatory,it gives idea about problem statement instead of code which sometimes is difficult to understand...some people have understood the question hence replied to it and i have accepted it as answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the success callback and call window.location.href to the action method which will return your view

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: url,
 data: data,
 success: callbackmethod,
 dataType: dataType
 });

function callbackMethod() {

window.location.href = "/YourController/YourView"
    }
```

In the Controller

```
 public ActionResult YourView()
 {
   //Any processing
   return View(YourViewModel);
  }
```